# How to implement a Javascript singleton to cache mongo collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, singleton, store

I've build the following singleton to be used as an in memory cache for mongo collections:

```
class CollectionStore {
    constructor(context) {
        console.log("Initializing collection store");

        this._data = {};
        this._context = context;
    }

    get(collection, id) {
        if (!this._data[collection])
            this.reset(collection).then(() => {
                return _getItem(collection, id);
            });
        else return _getItem(collection, id);
    }

    _getItem(collection, id) {
        console.log(
            "Getting item " + id + " from store collection " + collection
        );
        return this._data[collection].find((d) => d._id === id);
    }

    reset(collection) {
        console.log("Resetting store collection " + collection);
        mongoFind(this._context, collection).then((result) => {
            this._data[collection] = result;
        });
    }
}

const instance = new CollectionStore();
Object.freeze(instance);

export default instance;
```

`mongoFind` is an internal function that retrieves the full collection itens.

When instancing the store I'm getting the following error:

```
import { CollectionStore } from "../cache";

let context = {....} // Some access control stuff

let stores: {
    collectionStore: new CollectionStore(context) ** ERROR:  _cache.CollectionStore is not a constructor **
}
```

Any ideas of what my be going wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Your code exports an **instance** of `CollectionStore`.

Comment: So, remove `new` will solve it??

Comment: The exported value is an object, not a function. You can't call it with or without `new`.

Comment: Getting now `cache.CollectionStore is not a function` from `collectionStore: CollectionStore(context)`. If it is not a function, how to initialize it passing the needed `context`?? I'm confused...

Comment: Your module that *exports* the value calls `new CollectionStore()` and passes no "context" parameter. That creates an object. You can either use that object as the cache, or else export `CollectionStore` (the class) instead.

Comment: Hum... Got it. Thanks.